# Absolute and Relative Error of $x^y$

Tags: error-propagation

Suppose that we have two measured values $x$ and $y$ with maximum absolute errors of $e_x$ and $e_y$.

Is there a formula to find a good upper bound for absolute and relative error of $x^y$?

Comment: very interesting,is there any formula  related to this fact?but  is this statistical  values or what?for exmaple  is $e_x$  got by  some regression analysis?

Comment: No, they are not statistical. Suppose that we have measured $x$ and $y$ by some measurement tools $T_1$ and $T_2$, and these tools have maximum absolute errors of $e_x$ and $e_y$.

Comment: If you really know $e_x,e_y$ to be maximal absolute errors, and if you also know the measured values $x_0,y_0$, then you can place each of the true values of $x,y$ in intervals around their observed values, and just compute the maximal errors and relative errors without any fancy formula. Otherwise you might want to use differentials, which really give only approximate error bounds.

Answer (score 2):

The notation gets confusing, so allow me to set $e_x=\epsilon_x$ and $e_y=\epsilon_y$.  The trick here is to observe that $x^y = e^{y \log{x}}$ and Taylor expand as follows:

$$\begin{align}(x+\epsilon_x)^{y+\epsilon_y} &= e^{(y+\epsilon_y)\log{(x+\epsilon_x)}}\\ &=e^{y \log{(x+\epsilon_x)}} e^{\epsilon_y \log{(x+\epsilon_x)}} \\ &= e^{y \log{x} + y \log{(1+\epsilon_x/x)}}\left [1+ \epsilon_y \log{(x+\epsilon_x)}+ O(\epsilon_y^2)\right]\\ &= x^y e^{y[\epsilon_x/x + O(\epsilon_x^2)] } \left [1+ \epsilon_y \log{x} +\epsilon_y  \log{(1+\epsilon_x/x)}+ O(\epsilon_y^2)\right]\\ &= x^y \left (1+ \epsilon_x\frac{y}{x} + O(\epsilon_x^2)\right )\left [1+ \epsilon_y \log{x} +\epsilon_y  \frac{\epsilon_x}{x}+ O(\epsilon_y^2) + O(\epsilon_x^2 \epsilon_y)\right]\\ &= x^y \left (1 +  \epsilon_x\frac{y}{x} + \epsilon_y \log{x} +  \left( \frac{1+y \log{x}}{x}\right )\epsilon_x \epsilon_y+ O(\epsilon_y^2) + O(\epsilon_x^2 \epsilon_y) \right)  \end{align}$$

If you wish to ignore all second-order error terms, then you have

$$(x+\epsilon_x)^{y+\epsilon_y} \approx x^y \left (1 +  \epsilon_x\frac{y}{x} + \epsilon_y \log{x} \right )$$